# linux mysql-server can't find mysql_config

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, configuration

I have a running (in production) mysql instance on my linux server (ubuntu-10.10) however I cannot find my mysql_config file.

command and output:

```
~$ locate mysql_config
~$
```

I've heard/read that I need the libmysqlclient-dev package installed to be able to use mysql_config but I don't want to break my current production instance.  I want to make sure installing this dev package is not going to have adverse effects on my current mysql databases.

Furthermore, where can I find the source download for libmysqlclient-dev to install manually? In my current situation (behind corporate proxy) I am not permitted to use apt-get's.

**UPDATE**

this is stemming from attempting to install python-MySQLdb from source.  the setup.py file is requiring the mysql_config path and continues to break when trying to use anything but that file.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The `mysql_config` executable is by default located in the bin directory of the MySQL server installation if you install it from precompiled binaries. But if you install it using `apt-get` it may not exist on your server.

Try:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: Please see my OP as I cannot do apt-get's and need the actual source location of that package.

Comment: what you can do is you can manually download suitable mysql server precompiled version and extract mysql_config from tar.gz file. put it in your path. all it does is to read my.cnf file.

Comment: following the directions in your comment worked for getting the installer to find mysql_config.  Although I've run into other installation issues, they are not for this post.  Thank you.

Comment: This also solved an issue for me when `gem install mysql` failed.

Comment: there is not such a package in fedora, on doing ` sudo yum whatprovides "libmysqlclient*" ` you see that `mysql-community-libs-8.0.12-1.fc27.x86_64` package does the same thing on fedora, and then its already installed! What to do then?

Comment: `sudo apt install libmariadbclient-dev` works for me

Answer (score 2):

`yum install mariadb-devel` works for Centos 7 too, this puts the `mysql_config` into all the places that `pip install mysqlclient` requires/looks for it.

Comment: After spending 3 hours, this helped me!

Answer (score 0):

Try /etc/my.cnf, that is the standard file for mysql config.

Comment: /etc/mysql/my.cnf does exist...should I be using that instead of mysql_config?

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
find / -name my.cnf -type f
```

Comment: Does the setup.py file take command line arguments? Were you able to find your my.cnf file?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 13.04 installation, it is at `/usr/bin/mysql_config`

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora, install the `mariadb-devel` package, and you should have the binary.