# Compiling a MySQL Shared Object from source

Tags: mysql, plugins, centos

Please forgive my naivete, this is my first attempt to compile any piece of software from source.  I'm a long time user of the Handlersocket Plugin for Percona (MySQL) but they stopped including it after 5.6.  I'm moving up to MySQL 8 and I'm trying to compile the Handlersocket plugin from source but I'm stumbling.

First off, I've downloaded the source for handlersocket (https://github.com/DeNA/HandlerSocket-Plugin-for-MySQL), and the source for MySQL Server 8.0.17 (https://github.com/mysql/mysql-server). I've unpacked handlersocket into the `/source-downloads/` folder within the MySQL source, run the included `./autoconf.sh` and then `./configure`, but the latter is spouting errors...

```
checking mysql source... configure: error: --with-mysql-source=PATH is required for standalone build
```

I was able to adjust the call to `./configure --with-mysql-source=../..` but now it's returning an error regarding the binaray...

```
checking mysql binary... configure: error: mysql_config not found! You have to specify the directory where mysql_config resides to --with-mysql-bindir=PATH.
```

I tried searching for the `mysql_config` file anywhere in the source files (`find ../.. -name "mysql_config"`) but it's not found anywhere, what am I missing?  Is the file called something else? Is there something else I'm supposed to have downloaded?  I do have MySQL installed already (via YUM/DNF), can I point this at something from the existing install?

Comment: have you [installed this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8496660/linux-mysql-server-cant-find-mysql-config#answer-8496960)?

Comment: @WEBjuju thanks for the hint!  I've installed the `mysql-devel` and `mysql-libs` packages and `mysql_config` has now shown up in `/usr/bin/mysql_config`.  Will continue from here!

Comment: @WEBjuju After fixing an error with the `configure.ac` and using the resource you referenced, it looks like things are working now. Thanks again!